# Facebook pictures and posts that are available to non-friends

Tags: facebook, privacy

I viewed my Facebook profile from another account and I have some pictures and posts that are avaliable to non-friends. How can I change this? Under the privacy page everything is set to "friends only".

I still can't get it to work. I care mostly about pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Limit the audience for your past posts

[image: Audience settings]

http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy

After that recheck by viewing as a non-friend under the cog icon on your profile.

[image: View as another person]

If you are still seeing posts as non-friends, go to the individual post and change the audience

[image: Audience on a particular post]

Comment: I've clicked Manage Past Post Visibility and confirm but nothing happens.

Comment: @Celeritas go to each album and change the privacy

Comment: I can see where I go to view my album but what do I click on to change privacy settings?